# Why is MySQL root user not allowed in OpenCart installation?

Tags: mysql, opencart

For the past few days, I've been working with an [OpenCart installation](http://www.opencart.com/?route=download/download) <sup><sub>— v1.5.6.4 —</sub></sup> that uses MySQL's root user. So far, I've not noticed any oddities nor errors.

However, the 4th point of OpenCart's `install.txt` states:

> 4. Make sure you have installed a MySQL Database which has a user assigned to it
>
>    DO NOT USE YOUR ROOT USERNAME AND ROOT PASSWORD

Why does the readme file explicit the non-usage of MySQL's root user?

**What errors will there be  when OpenCart is set up with MySQL's root user?**

Comment: root = superuser. Consider what happens if a bug is discovered in opencart that allows arbitrary DB operations (e.g. an sql injection vulnerability). If OpenCart is connecting as the mysql root user, now whoever's hacking into opencart has TOTAL access to ALL databases in your mysql install. Public facing code that interfaces with a DB should NEVER have root privileges, and only the privs necessary to work (e.g. select/insert/update/delete).

Comment: @MarcB, Ic, so it's indeed not really a hard requirement then.

Comment: not a hard requirement, but don't ignore it either. running your DB connection with root privs is pretty much one of the stupidest things you can do, unless you're building something like phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any errors but it's strongly advisable to not use the root user unless you absolutely have to.  This is for security reasons.  Set up a DB user that has just enough permissions to allow OpenCart to work and use that user instead.

This is advisable for any system, not just OpenCart.  They're just giving you some security advice.

Comment: What's the minimum set of permission an installation needs?

Comment: From memory, I think you need to give it CREATE, DROP, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.  You can always give more permissions later if you get error messages.

Comment: DROP shouldn't be necessary

Comment: I've come across an error in the past where DROP was required during initial installation.

Comment: The initial installation can always be done with the ROOT user, just for simplicity, and after initial installation the user should be changed to user with only `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` privileges. It would be even more secure if OpenCart had implemented the *non-deleting "delete"* logic - in that case even the `DELETE` privilege wouldn't be necessary.